# eslint with create-react-app facebook incubator

Tags: reactjs, eslint

i can not use eslint with create-react-app

```
eslint src/App.js
```

it said in the console

```
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app'
Referenced from: /home/user-name/Code/react/dev.app/.eslintrc
    at ModuleResolver.resolve (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
    at resolve (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:515:25)
    at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:584:26)
    at configExtends.reduceRight.e (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:421:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:405:28)
    at loadFromDisk (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:556:22)
    at Object.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:592:20)
    at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:228:44)
    at Config.getConfigHierarchy (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:182:43)
```

the eslint works properly in the global and i have tried to install eslint-config-react-app in the global also the local project folder. My project folder looks like

```
node_modules
public
src
.eslintrc
.gitignore
.README.md
package.json
```

everything seems to be good ? how can i resolve the problem, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like, you haven't installed some eslint packages to your node modules, try:

```
yarn add --dev eslint-config-react-app
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-react-app
```

Comment: i have installed it. there's eslint-config-react-app existing in node_modules folder . nothing happens

Comment: after reinstalling almost everything, now it works, not sure what wrongs here, maybe incompatible version packages

Comment: @mhdev - Make sure that you're NPM installing in the correct node_modules directory. For me, that meant installing to the node_modules at the root of my project, not the node_modules inside the react-ui directory.